# SVM Classifier with HOG Features

Tags: svm, image-processing, object-detection, optical-character-recognition

I am interested in having a system to detect and recognize speed limits from traffic signs. The detection part works fine, meaning that I am able to detect them inside any image. Now I would like to classify the result of the detector.

What is the correct way to do that? For example, I would like to recognize a speed limit of 50. Should I train an SVM with traffic signs of 50 as positive samples and as negative samples use what? Should I use all of the remaining speed limits (20, 30, 40, 60, 70....) as negative training samples? Is this the only way? Is there any other way (again using SVM) to do that? I am using Matlab's svm.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is very similar to hand-written digit recognition, which is the famous problem in supervised learning.

Tensorflow has a nice tutorial and a set of packages dealing with it. (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html#mnist-for-ml-beginners)

The only thing left is you need a set of labeled data: pictures that has digits in it, captured from the signs, labeled by somebody. If you have the detected parts of the images, crop the parts down and ship them to Mechanical Turk (https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome). If you don't have $$, you can share the labeling tasks with one or two of your friends/colleagues. 100 labels per day, takes 30 mins a day for about two week to get a sizable dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Usually those signs have predefined sizes. If you are able to reliably detect them, I would expect some basic OCR system to be able to solve it. More concretely: it should be easy enough to rescale the sign to a predefined size (so that numbers have also the size you can expect), and then segment them based on the knowledge you have about those signs (white numbers on blue background, or black numbers on white background,...). Finally, some pretrained digit recognizer should be able to read them out.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to divide your system in two different classifiers: one for detecting traffic signals in images. Then I´d train a second classifier to detect numbers characters *inside* traffic signals, recognizing the whole number or one digit each time. This division makes the job easier for both classifiers and recognizing each digit instead of the whole number also makes it more robust to traffic signs out of your training sample.